# SPARQL query to return a list of names of the most famous people

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm a SPARQL newbie, trying to get a list of the most "famous" people in the world who are still alive. This is for a solution where we're trying to trap people applying for something under well-known but fake names. The only method I can think of so far to identify the most famous names is to do a sitelinks count, however the problem is it times out, of course.

Is there some way I can optimise this query, or maybe some other method I can use to get to the same goal?

```
SELECT ?person ?label (COUNT(DISTINCT(?sitelink)) as ?sites)
WHERE {  
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5. #human
  
  MINUS { ?person wdt:P570 [ ] . } #exclude where date of death is anything, i.e. they're alive
  
  ?sitelink schema:about ?person .  
  
  ?person rdfs:label ?label . # getting the label of ?person
  FILTER (lang(?label) = "en") # filtering ?label to English labels  
  }
GROUP BY ?person ?label
ORDER BY DESC(?sites)
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: you can run the query on the qlever endpoint: https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/yotMc1 - just use this query then: `PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
SELECT ?person 
(COUNT(DISTINCT(?sitelink)) as ?sites)
WHERE { 
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5. #human
  MINUS { ?person wdt:P570 ?d . } #exclude where date of death is anything, i.e. they're alive
  ?sitelink schema:about ?person . 
  }
GROUP BY ?person
ORDER BY DESC(?sites)
LIMIT 100`

Comment: Awesome, that works thanks! Just for completeness for anyone else, I also got the labels by adding "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"